# Assigning an ID column that matches a specific column

Tags: python, pandas

suppose I have a data frame:

```
Intro    Animal

Hello    Dog
Hello    Cat
Hello    Bird
Bye      Horse
Bye      Pig
Hi       Zebra
```

How would I be able to add the "ID" column that matches the Intro column? :

```
ID    Intro    Animal

1     Hello    Dog
1     Hello    Cat
1     Hello    Bird
2     Bye      Horse
2     Bye      Pig
3     Hi       Zebra
```

Comment: What is the desired result? You want rows only that have a value of `Hello` or `Hi` in `Intro` ?

Comment: The desired result is to add an ID column that would give all the hello values an ID of 1, then all the Bye values an ID of 2 and all the Hi values a value of 3. In this case, there are 3 hellos so the first three rows of the ID column are only 1's

Answer (score 1):

One method: create a mapping (dict) of the unique values, then map to a new column:

```
group_number = dict(zip(df.Intro.unique(), range(1, len(df))))
df["ID"] = df.Intro.map(group_number)
```

result:

```
   Intro Animal  ID
0  Hello    Dog   1
1  Hello    Cat   1
2  Hello   Bird   1
3    Bye  Horse   2
4    Bye    Pig   2
5     Hi  Zebra   3
```

You can optionally set this as the index `df.set_index("ID")` but maybe not recommended as it's not a unique value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use groupby and transform count to get this

```
c = ['Intro','Animal']
d = [['Hello','Dog'],
['Hello'    ,'Cat'],
['Hello'    ,'Bird'],
['Hai'      ,'Paper'],
['Hello'    ,'Mouse'],
['Hai'      ,'Salt'],
['Bye'      ,'Horse'],
['Bye'      ,'Pig'],
['Hi'       ,'Zebra']]

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(d,columns=c)

df.sort_values('Intro',inplace=True)
df['grp'] = df['Intro'] != df['Intro'].shift() 
#for numbers you can use df['Intro'].diff().ne(0) 
#however using inquality check is more versatile for strings

df['ID'] = df['grp'].cumsum()
df.drop('grp',axis=1,inplace=True)
df.reset_index(inplace=True,drop=True)


print (df)
```

This will give you:

```
   Intro Animal  ID
0    Bye  Horse   1
1    Bye    Pig   1
2    Hai  Paper   2
3    Hai   Salt   2
4  Hello    Dog   3
5  Hello    Cat   3
6  Hello   Bird   3
7  Hello  Mouse   3
8     Hi  Zebra   4
```

Comment: Are you particular if `Hello` is `1` ?

Comment: I would recommend going with @anon01 answer as the solution converts the data into a dict and maps it back for the assignment